# Prove that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\mathbb{R}^2=Span\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$. Does anybody know how to prove that if there is a linear tranformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(\alpha)=\beta, T(\beta)=\gamma, T(\gamma)=\alpha$, it is $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0$?

Comment: Think about what $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 0$ means geometrically. It means that after the transformation is applied, if you connect each vector head-to-tail, you'll end up back where you started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$ is linearly dependent (otherwise $\dim(\mathbb{R}^2)=3$, a contradiction) so $c_1\alpha+c_2\beta+c_3\gamma=0$ where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are not all zero.

Then $0=T(c_1\alpha+c_2\beta+c_3\gamma)=c_1T(\alpha)+c_2T(\beta)+c_3T(\gamma)=c_1\beta+c_2\gamma+c_3\alpha$

Similarly, we can get $0=c_1\gamma+c_2\alpha+c_3\beta$

Adding these up we get $(c_1+c_2+c_3)(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)=0$

Do you think you can show that $c_1+c_2+c_3\ne 0$? I encourage you to figure this out for yourself, so I will show this in a spoiler.

> Since $\mathrm{span}\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}=\mathbb{R^2}$ we have that the column space of the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta&\gamma \end{bmatrix}$ has dimension $2$. So $\mathrm{nullity}(A)=1$ by the Rank-Nullity Theorem. Therefore, the nullspace of $A$ is spanned by one vector.
>
>  But we know that $[c_1,c_2,c_3]^T$, $[c_3,c_1,c_2]^T$, and $[c_2,c_3,c_1]^T$ are nonzero vectors in the nullspace of $A$, so they all must be parallel. From this, we easily find that $c_1=c_2=c_3$ and they are not all zero, so $c_1+c_2+c_3\ne 0$

Comment: I don't understand. Suppose $\gamma = \frac12(\alpha+\beta)$ to start with. Then won't you in fact have $c_1+c_2+c_3=0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, but then there either exists no such linear transformation, or $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$ does not span $\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 1):

Since in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you **can't have more of two vectors linearly independent**, thus if $$Span\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}=\mathbb{R}^2$$ one vector must be a linear combination of two.

Let's exclude the trivial cases with 2 vectors collinear, assume wlog:

$$\gamma = a\alpha + b\beta$$

with $a,b\neq0$

By definition of T:

$$\gamma=T(\beta)=T(\frac1b \gamma-\frac{a}{b}\alpha)=\frac1b \alpha-\frac{a}{b}\beta$$

Since the representation of $\gamma$ is unique:

$$a=\frac1b$$

$$b=-\frac{a}{b}$$

> $$\implies a=b=-1 \implies \alpha+\beta+\gamma=0 \quad \square$$

Comment: That doesn't show $\alpha+\beta++\gamma=0$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; the OP wants to show a specific linear combination of $\{\alpha, \beta, \gamma\}$ is $0$,, not just that one combination exists.

Comment: You are right sorry, I complete teh answer!

Comment: I’ve completed the answer!

Comment: You didn't explain why $a=\frac1b$. You need to explain why there can't be 2 different linear combinations of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to give you $\gamma$. This is what the spoiler in my answer explains.

Comment: a=1/b comes directly from the equations!

Comment: No it doesn't, unless you've explained why they can't be different linear combinations to get the same vector. Also, your answer still doesn't show that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0$

Comment: Sorry but I really don’t get your point of view. I’ve assumed that $\gamma$ is a linear combination of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and then I’ve shown directly  that for the given T the assumption implies that $\alpha+\beta +\gamma=0$. Please explain better what is wrong in the proof. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, you state that $\gamma=a\alpha+b\beta$ and $\gamma=\frac1b \alpha-\frac{a}b\beta$. However, you are not allowed to just assert that $a=\frac1b$ and $b=-\frac ab$ unless you establish that $\gamma$ has a **unique** representation as a linear combination of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Also, you need to show that $b\ne 0$ because you are dividing by it. If you show these things, I think your answer is valid.

Comment: Let's do not consider for a moment the trivial case with a=0 or b=0 (I agree with you I've to mention it). I've stated "\gamma=a\alpha+b\beta" and applied $T(\beta)=\gamma$ by the given hypotesis. Why should be the representation of \gamma not unique?

Comment: I agree that these issues can be resolved, but you still need to explain them in your answer. The representation of $\gamma$ as a linear combination of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is unique only if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are linearly independent.

Comment: But they are linearly independent for the hypotesis that they span $\mathbb{R^2}$! Anyway, I've added a note on trivial cases, the proof is not substantially modified. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Of course I know that they are linearly independent because they span $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm just saying you should say that in your answer. I don't think the cases with $2$ collinear vectors are trivial; you should show that case as well.

Comment: I've revised completely my work in another answer. Now I Think it's more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, $T^3=I$. So the minimal polynomial is $p\in\mathbb R[t]$, with $\deg(p)\le2$, and such that $p$ divides $$t^3-1=(t-1)(t^2+t+1).$$
Since $t^2+t+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb R[t]$, the minimal polynomial is $t-1$ or $t^2+t+1$. But $T\ne I$. So the minimal polynomial is $t^2+t+1$.

Hence $$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=(I+T+T^2)\alpha=0.$$

Comment: very nice proof. Could you please give your advice on mine, do you think it can work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume wlog $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as basis and $\gamma=a\alpha+b\beta$, thus T is represented by:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & a \\ 1 & b\end{bmatrix}\implies T(\gamma)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & a \\ 1 & b\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ab \\ a+b^2\end{bmatrix}=\alpha=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

That is

$$\begin{cases}ab=1\\a+b^2=0\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}a=\frac1b\\b^3+1=0\end{cases}\implies a=b=-1\implies \alpha+\beta+\gamma=0 \quad \square$$

**NOTE**

Since ab=1, trivial cases with a=0 or b=0 are excluded.